# Obtener el indice de un array en twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trabajo con twig, symfony, deseo obtener un elemento de una array por su indice lo trabajo de la siguiente manera y funciona bien

```
{% for calificacion in matriculado.getCalificaciones() %}
        {# {% for calcurso in calificaciones %} #}
            <td>{{ calificacion.q1P1N1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ calificacion.q1P1N2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ calificacion.q1P1N3 }}</td>  
            <td>{{ calificacion.q1P1N4 }}</td>  
            <td></td>   
            <td></td>   
            <td>{{ calificacion.getPromedioFinal }}</td>    
            <td></td>   
        {# {% endfor %} #}
    {% endfor %}
```

Al tratar de usar su indice no funciona muestro el código

```
<td>{{ calificacion['q1P1N1'] }}</td>
```

Estoy recorriendo una colección para obtener sus datos entonces es un `array`, por que me sale este tipo de mensaje en postman `Impossible to access a key "q1P1N1" on an object of class "App\MultiacademicoBundle\Entity\Calificaciones" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface.` me esta diciendo que es una clase mas no un `array`, porque? si estoy recorriendo un `array`

Dentro de Matriculado tengo una colección `calificaciones`

```
/**
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getCalificaciones($promocion = false)
```

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo así, he probado con `""` y no funciona. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Prueba usar un índice base 0, calificacion[0], calificacion[1] y así sucesivamente

Comment: Todo depende del tipo de array que tengas, a lo mejor ni siquiera es un array y es un objeto, trata de usarlo como objeto y no como array

Comment: @Marcos Estoy trabajando en una api y para hacer las pruebas uso postman, el código esta en una plantilla `twig` crees que se pueda hacer un `dump`?

Comment: @Marcos no se puede hacer el dump por que info es mucha y te puedo asegurar que si trae datos por que estoy llenando un reporte

Comment: Como le paso el indice [0] ó ['q1P1N1'] e intentado de varias maneras pero nada según tu ejemplo donde va el indice

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118220/discussion-between-pedro-avila-and-marcos).

Comment: @Marcos me da este error Unknown `"get_type" filter.` no reconoce `get_type`

Comment: ¿Podes intentar hacerlo de [esta forma](https://pastebin.pl/view/436c1cc5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta a mi problema se hace de la siguiente manera.

```
<td>{{ attribute(calificacion, 'q1P1N1') }}</td>
<td>{{ attribute(calificacion, 'q1P1N2') }}</td>
<td>{{ attribute(calificacion, 'q1P1N3') }}</td>    
<td>{{ attribute(calificacion, 'q1P1N4') }}</td>
```

[Twig for Template Designers](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html)